# Show cumulative SalesAmount column chart to max date in slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am looking to build a column chart in Power BI that displays cumulative sales by month up to max date selected in date slicer. I have a supplementary Date2 table that is related to Date table (inactive relation). Tried something like this, but I keep getting all the months irrespective which one is selected in slicer:

```
Sales to date selected = 
VAR ReferenceDate = MAX ( 'Date'[Date] )
Return
    CALCULATE (  [SalesAmount],
        ALLEXCEPT('Date', 'Date'[Year]),
        FILTER( all(Date2[Date]), Date2[Date] <= MAX( Date2[Date] ) 
                               && Date2[Date] <= ReferenceDate),
        USERELATIONSHIP ( 'Date'[Date], Date2[Date] )
    )
```

This is what I get as a result (Slicer selects month 7):
[image]

It looks like CALCULATE does not honor filter Date2[Date] <= ReferenceDate . What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hi @ggv. what logic made you decide to create 2nd date table ? Also, please share your data model, columns, and sample of data for us to help you.

Comment: Hi Ozan,
Well, I am really not aware of other way to display months from 1 to 7 when I have slicer on Date that selects month 7 only.

Comment: OK. Your model is not incorrect. Just only 1 date table. You can use ALLSELECTED('Date'[Date]) . It will give you the max value among date values selected in the slicer. Like this: VAR ReferenceDate = ALLSELECTED(MAX ( 'Date'[Date] )) then use it in a filter constraint then.

Answer (score 0):

OK, looks like this scenario solves my issue. I removed inactive relationship between Date and Date2 and introduced active relationship from Sales to Date2.

```
Sales to date selected = 
VAR ReferenceDate = MAX ( 'Date'[Date] )
Return
IF( MAX(Date2[Date]) <= ReferenceDate,
    CALCULATE (  [SalesAmount],
        ALLEXCEPT('Date', 'Date'[Year]),
        Date2[Date] <= MAX( Date2[Date] )  
    )  
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a correction to your code; but It seems that It takes a long time for it to be approved by community members:

So test this:

```
Sales to date selected =
VAR ReferenceDate =
    MAX ( ALLSELECTED ( 'Date2'[Date] ) )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        [SalesAmount],
        FILTER ( ALLEXCEPT ( 'Date2', 'Date2'[Year] ), 'Date2'[Date] <= ReferenceDate )
    )
```

Or This:

```
Sales to date selected =
VAR ReferenceDate =
    MAX ( ALLSELECTED ( 'Date2'[Date] ) )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        [SalesAmount],
        FILTER ( ALL ( 'Date2'[Date] ), 'Date2'[Date] <= ReferenceDate )
    )
```